# screen goes black for a second with display port

Tags: display, vga, dvi

I have a hp elitedesk 800 g2 twr, with intel core i5 6500, I am using the integrated graphics hd 530, when using the display port on the pc, from time to time the screen goes black for a second, but when I switch to a vga cable every thing works fine. The monitor and the display port cable are confirmed to be functional using another pc and I am using the latest intel driver for the hd 530. So is the problem in the cpu itself or the motherboard display port ?

Comment: It's a guess either way. Replacing the mainboard will be less expensive than replacing the CPU, but buying an inexpensive discrete graphics card is probably the cheapest and simplest option.

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, The monitor and the display port cable were tested with another pc and they work fine, it's pc probably causing this.

Comment: How about switching to VGA, then uninstall the Intel 530 driver completely. Now go to the official HP website and install the latest version from the self service desk manually via device manager. Make sure internet is not connected otherwise windows update will just install it via the Microsoft Servers, which isn't always the driver HP recommend you use:

https://support.hp.com/in-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-elitedesk-800-g2-small-form-factor-pc/7633277

Comment: @Mastaxx, I've downloaded the "Intel Video Driver and Control" from hp site, but when I run igxpin.exe I get an error "this operating system is not supported" even though I am running win10